# Laravel where statement and pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have an SQL search where I use Eloquent whereRaw, and than paginatate results.

**Proplem:** the results are paginated and if I navigate to the next page the results will  be gone and it will just "SELECT All " bacause laravel's pagination sends only ?page= GET request.

code:

```
if (Input::has('city')) {
        $query .= ' and city = '.Input::get('city');
    }
    if (Input::has('area')) {
        $query .= ' and area = '.Input::get('area');
    }
    if (Input::has('sub_location')) {
        $query .= ' and sub_location = '.Input::get('sub_location');
    }
    if (Input::has('rent')) {
        $query .= ' and rent = '.Input::get('rent');
    }
    if (Input::has('price_min') && Input::has('price_max')) {
        $query .= ' and price < '.Input::get('price_max').' and price >'.Input::get('price_min');
    }


    $listings = ListingDB::whereRaw($query)->paginate(5);


    return View::make('page.index')->with('title','Home')->with('listings',$listings);
```

so when I navigate to the next page all the Input is gone because laravel generates pagination only with ?page= GET variable, how can I solve it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append you query string to the pagination link

```
{!! $listings->appends(Input::all())->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Appending To Pagination Links

You may add to the query string of pagination links using the appends method. For example, to append &sort=votes to each pagination link, you should make the following call to appends:

{!! $listings->appends(['sort' => 'value'])->links() !!}

So in your case you need to add to pagination links like this if you have city and rent search applied then

{!! $listings->appends(['city' => 'london', 'rent' => 5000])->links() !!}

This will sort out your problem.